# How do I list only the valid mounted disk partitions using Get-PSDrive?

Tags: windows, powershell, mount

I just discovered PowerShell literally yesterday and I love it.

I am trying to list all the *valid mounted partitions* so I can make them a variable and run `chkdsk` on them.  The problem is that I don't want to detect backup partitions on the machine.  The computer I'm using to write and test this script doesn't have any backup/not-mounted partitions.  I am thoroughly reading `get-help get-psdrives` but I don't have the knowledge to understand if the options can do what I need (or if they already are doing it).

Answer (score 3):

This will get you all the drives that you can run `chkdsk` on:

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem
```

---

**Edit:** This will get you the mounted drives that are either [Local Disks (3) or removable disks (2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
Get-WmiObject -class “Win32_LogicalDisk" | ?{ @(2, 3) -contains $_.DriveType }
```

Comment: Thank you!  That is exactly what I  was using but I wasnt able to confirm if that is listing only mounted drives.  I appreciate it.

Comment: actually I am still having a problem.  It seems I also need to limit the list to non-network drives and
Get-PSDrive | where {$_.Provider.Name -eq "FileSystem"}
does list network drives.  Do you know how I produce a list without them or filter them out?

Comment: I "powershellized" your scripts just to show a bit more flexibility on the powershell side.

Comment: @x0n That looks cleaner. Thanks. (I've done with a C# mentality)